# Trouble setting up openVPN/VPN

Tags: vpn, iptables, openvpn, vps

I'm having trouble setting up a VPN on my VPS that's running Ubuntu 11.04. I'm been following this guide http://tipupdate.com/how-to-install-openvpn-on-ubuntu-vps/

I'm able to start the VPN, but the command it tell's me to do after I start the VPN doesn't work for me. I've tried it about 5 different way's and i'll show you what i get now.

```
:~# iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

:~# iptables -A FORWARD state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
Bad argument `state'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I just can't get that to work and the VPN doesn't seem to be workign with out it.

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your FORWARD chain is missing, you can create it with:

```
sudo iptables -N FORWARD
```

Consider using `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` (or `iptables-apply` for remote machines) for saving/applying rules.

If you still have issues, contact your VPS provider for more help.